# How to use Liquid include variable within a for loop?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have this Liquid template which looks like this:

```
# /_includes/slideshow.html
{% for image in {{ include.images }} %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

which I'm trying to use with a YAML file (for my Jekyll site) like this:

```
# /index.md
{% include slideshow.html images='site.data.homepage_images' %}
```

The reason I see this failing is because my include variable `{{ include.images }}` resolves to a *string* within the for loop. Is there a different way to accomplish this? I'm still rather new to Liquid, YAML, Jekyll, and well, web development altogether, so any help in doing this is much appreciated!

(Note: the problem goes away if I replace `{{ include.images }}` with `site.data.homepage_images`.)

Additionally, the reason why I'm doing this (and why that crude fix isn't the solution I'm looking for) is for the ability to inject my image slideshow elsewhere around my site. It'd save a lot of code to abuse my include variable in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax in for loop is : `{% for image in include.images %}`

Comment: Ah, I see it now. It was farther down the page on Jekyll's [Includes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#passing-references-to-yaml-files-as-parameter-values) page. Anyway, thanks for the help!